# Error bounds for Newton's Method

Tags: calculus

My calculus book (Calculus, a complete course 8th) says:

> **Theorem 2 - Error bounds for Newton's Method:** Suppose that $f$, $f'$, $f''$ are continuous on an interval $I$ containing $x_n$, $x_{n+1}$ and a root $x=r$ of $f(x)=0$. Suppose also that there exist constants $K>0$ and $L>0$ such that for all $x$ in $I$ we have (i) $|f''(x)|\le K$ and (ii) $|f'(x)|\ge L$. Then (a) $|x_{n+1}-r|\le\frac{K}{2L}|x_{n+1}-x_n|^2$ and (b) $|x_{n+1}-r|\le\frac{K}{2L}|x_n-r|^2$.

**Question:** Being a relative beginner in math I simply do not understand what the purpose of the above statement is and what it means. Could anyone please explain? I do know in general what Newton's Method is and that it's function is $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$. I suppose (i) means that $|f''(x)|$ isn't infinite and (ii) means that $|f'(x)|$ isn't $0$. But what do (a) and (b) mean? I have no clue on how to interpret these statements, let alone see the purpose. What are error bounds? How are they relevant in this case? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: (b) says that the error decreases quadratically, so if your error at the last step was 0.01, the next step it'll roughly be (0.01)^2, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Newton's method is to find root of a function by iteration. So motivation here is to understand how accurate the estimation to the root and how fast the estimation approaching to the root. (a) gives a good way to estimate the accuracy.

for (i), we don't want it curved too much and, for (ii), we don't want it too flat.